# Unsigned number instead of checking invariant in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

If you know a number cannot be negative, which design is better in a DDD model ?

```
public record Quantity(uint Number);
```

```
public record Quantity()
{
    public int number { get; init; }
    public Quantity(int number)
    {
        if (number < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Quantity must be positive");
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `Always-valid` approach there equivalents. Both would guarantee that Quantity is always positive. You might prefer the second one, for the more clear exception message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you know a number cannot be negative, which design is better in a DDD model ?

I can't think of a single DDD example I have seen that uses unsigned types as a general purpose data structure.

The general rule for unsigned types is that you use default to using a signed type, and use unsigned types only when appropriate to the specific task at hand.

[Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types)

> Do not use an unsigned type merely to assert that a variable is non-negative.

[CPP Core Guidelines: ES106](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es106-dont-try-to-avoid-negative-values-by-using-unsigned)

> Don't try to avoid negative values by using unsigned

Stroustrup, Sutter and Carruth were of unanimous opinion in 2013

- [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Puio5dly9N8&t=2559s)
- [Transcript](https://www.nayuki.io/page/unsigned-int-considered-harmful-for-java) courtesy of Nayuki (near bottom of page)

Online discussions that agree with the above

- [Jacob Egner](https://jacobegner.blogspot.com/2019/11/unsigned-integers-are-dangerous.html)
- [Chris Cannam](http://soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned.html)